# Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined when npm i -g firebase-tools

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-tools

**Environment:** 
Platform: Ubuntu 
Firebase -V: 7.0.2 
info using npm@6.9.0 
info using node@v10.16.0 

**reproduction:** 
firebase projects:list 
projects:list is not a Firebase command 
npm i -g firebase-tools 
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR!     /home/.npm/_logs/2021-04-29T17_50_10_133Z-debug.log